# iText 5.5.x - Java - page breaks

Tags: java, itext

How can i add page breaks to a document using Java iText 5.5.x using the y position on the page? I have overridden the Div class to use a custom HTML tag, which denotes what content to keep together (because the conformance list [http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/CSS-conformance-list.htm] indicates that page breaks in HTML must be 'always'). I can't seem to establish how to break when the content will be greater than the size I want on the page. The PDF generation is *not* using the "standard" way of creating a PDF, but getting content from parsing a HTML file.

Below is what I have for the Div class:

```
class PageBreak extends Div {
private Document document;
private PdfWriter writer;
private float breakPoint;
private float signatureArea = 80;

public PageBreak(Document document, PdfWriter writer) {
    this.document = document;
    this.writer = writer;
    this.breakPoint = (document.top() - signatureArea - 40 /*padding*/);
}

@Override
public List<com.itextpdf.text.Element> end(WorkerContext ctx, Tag tag, List<com.itextpdf.text.Element> currentContent) {
    System.out.println("END POS: " + writer.getVerticalPosition(true));
    System.out.println("writer.getVerticalPosition(true) " + writer.getVerticalPosition(true));
    System.out.println("breakPoint: " + breakPoint);

    boolean newPage = writer.getVerticalPosition(true) > breakPoint;

    if(newPage) {
        System.out.println("breaking");
        document.newPage();
    }

    return currentContent;
}

@Override
public List<com.itextpdf.text.Element> start(WorkerContext ctx, Tag tag) {
    System.out.println("START POS: " + writer.getVerticalPosition(true));
    System.out.println("writer.getVerticalPosition(true) " + writer.getVerticalPosition(true));
    System.out.println("breakPoint: " + breakPoint);
    return new ArrayList<com.itextpdf.text.Element>(0);
  }}
```

An example of the HTML:

```
 <pagebreak>
 <table><tr><td class="section-h3">A table</td></tr></table>
 <table>
 <tr>
 <td class="withback-70">Reviewed By</td>
 <td class="withoutback-70">Jim</td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </pagebreak>
```

This is the code to convert / parse from HTML to PDF:

```
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, outputStream);
    writer.setPageEvent(new HeaderFooter(mappedMasterIncident));
    document.setPageSize(PageSize.LETTER);
    document.setMargins(18, 18, 18, 95);
    document.open();

    HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);
    //not working
    //TagProcessorFactory factory = Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory();
    //factory.addProcessor(new PageBreak(document, writer), "pagebreak");
    //htmlContext.setTagFactory(factory);
    htmlContext.setTagFactory(Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory());
    htmlContext.setImageProvider(new Base64ImageProvider());

    CSSResolver cssResolver = new StyleAttrCSSResolver();
    cssResolver.addCssFile("file:///C|/Users/jim.willmore/Desktop/pdf.css", true);
    Pipeline<?> pipeline = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver,new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, new PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer)));

    XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(pipeline, true);
    XMLParser p = new XMLParser( worker);
    p.parse(templateReader);

    document.close();
```

Comment: It's hard to help without any code  The straight forward answer to *How can i add page breaks to a document using Java iText 5.5.x using the y position on the page?* would be **by calling `Document.newPage()` according to the position** but I assume that doesn't help, does it?

Comment: I can post code, but it's not doing what I want. More importantly, I may creating more work for myself than I need to. I've also tried modifying the margins in hopes of having the API figure out where best to break pages, but have failed. The main problem is the footer on each page overlapping the content. Breaking the pages so the footer shows up in the same place, and not overlapping content, has been a chore.

Comment: *footer shows up in the same place, and not overlapping content, has been a chore* - that usually is trivial, merely a matter of choosing coordinates for footers in the margin area.

Comment: mkl - Thanks for the information. It appears I was setting the margins for the page improperly. I was setting the margins *after* document.open(), instead of *before* the document.open() method call. The footer is now displaying as it is supposed to; no overlapping content.

Comment: I am still unable to control page breaking. Does anyone have any insight?

Comment: Looking at your code you try to use `PdfWriter` y position while you still collect content in a list, i.e. the content has not yet gone to the writer and its y position still is at the top of page 1. That indeed cannot work. Unfortunately I'm not into this `XmlWorker` business and cannot help, but others most likely can.